# How serialize to stream with JSON.NET on F#?

Tags: json, f#, xamarin.android, json.net

I need to send JSON to `WebResourceResponse`:

```
override this.ShouldInterceptRequest(view:WebView, request:IWebResourceRequest) =
    let rows = Customer.fakeData 1 // Array of records

    let st = Shared.jsonToStream(rows)
    new WebResourceResponse("application/javascript", "UTF-8", st)
```

But don't see how do that. I use Json.NET and F#.

When I run:

```
let jsonToStream(value:'T) =
    let serializer = new JsonSerializer()
    let std = new IO.MemoryStream()
    let sw = new IO.StreamWriter(std)
    let json = new JsonTextWriter(sw)
    serializer.Serialize(json, value)
    //std.Position <- 0L
    std
```

the response returns as a blank string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the following issues:

1. You need to dispose of your `StreamWriter` and `JsonTextWriter` so that the serialized JSON is flushed to the underlying stream.  This can be done by replacing `let` with [`use`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/resource-management-the-use-keyword).

   However, you need to do so without closing the underlying stream `std`, since you are going to read from it later.
2. Having done so, you need to reset the position of the `std` stream after `sw` and `json` have gone out of scope and been disposed.  If you try to reset the position before then it won't work.

Thus the following will work:

```
let jsonToStream(value:'T) =
    let serializer = new JsonSerializer()
    let std = new IO.MemoryStream()
    (   use sw = new StreamWriter(std, new UTF8Encoding(false, true), 1024, true)
        use json = new JsonTextWriter(sw, CloseOutput = false)
        serializer.Serialize(json, value))
    std.Position <- 0L
    std
```

Note the use of parentheses to restrict the scope of `sw` and `json` so that `std.Position` can be reset after they go out of scope.  `jsonToStream(rows)` will now return an open `MemoryStream` containing complete, serialized JSON and positioned at the beginning.

Sample working [f# fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xkmADS).